# Remove element from an array

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I am looking for some help with removing an element from an array. My array `$rooms` holds events per rooms. Each room has its own array and each event has its own array within the room array. I loop through `$rooms` and display the room ID and within this loop I loop through the events for that room and display their contents. I would like to remove the array for the event that has been displayed so I don't have spend time comparing it when I repeat the same loop.

Below is an example of the process I am describing. I know it makes no sense to delete the element in this logic as I am using foreach, but within my application the logic of the function requires it..

**$rooms**

```
array(3) 
{ 
  [1]=> array(2) 
    { 
       ["rid"]=> string(1) "1" 
       ["events"]=> array(0) 
         { } 
    } 
  [2]=> array(2) 
    { 
       ["rid"]=> string(1) "2" 
       ["events"]=> array(0) 
         { } 
    } 
  [3]=> array(2) 
    { 
       ["rid"]=> string(1) "3" 
       ["events"]=> array(2) 
         { 
           [0]=> array(7) 
             { 
               ["lname"]=> string(20) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
             } 
           [1]=> array(7) 
             { 
               ["lname"]=> string(10) "yyyyyyyyyy" 
             } 
          }  
      } 
}
```

**loop**

```
foreach ($rooms as $room):
   echo $room['rid'];
   foreach ($room['events'] as $event):
       echo $event['lname'];
```

If you could tell me where within the `foreach` I should put the code and how should the code look like that would be really great. I think it should be right after `echo $event['lname']`, but I can't figure out how to locate the element that is displayed so I can unset it..

Thank you all for reading, 
looking forward to your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply unset the event after echoing it, but you'll need to reference it from $rooms, so you need to use the key's at each level. Try this:

```
foreach($rooms as $i => $room) {
    echo $room['rid'];
    foreach($room['events'] as $j => $event) {
        echo $event['lname'];
        unset($rooms[$i]['events'][$j]);
    }
}
```

You can see an example of it working [here](https://eval.in/139556).

Comment: Did that and then I have put `echo '<div>'.var_dump($room).'</div>';` and the displayed vardump still has the events in it. I have the echo after the inside foreach is closed

Comment: @CreamWhippedAirplane I had a typo in the unset, I'd put `$room` instead of `$rooms`, which I've now corrected. Check the updated eval.in link and you can see me dumping it and it working.

Comment: Doesn't want to work for me :/ Can't tell what I am doing wrong. Especially since it works in you're eval. Could the problem be that in my application the inside `foreach` is enclosed in one more `foreach` that looks like this `for($x=0; $x < 31; $x++):` Basically what I am doing is generating a table where I use the `rid` as left heading and then generate 31 day cells using this foreach and on each day I loop through the `$room['events']` and see if there is an event that matches the currently generated cell day...

Comment: Oh. I take it back! I must have been dumping the array in a wrong spot or something. I dumped `$rooms` after all the loops were closed and the events are gone. So thank you!